# π approximation - Leibniz series

Tags: python

I am having concerns with the validity of the code I wrote for the exercise from the book **Python Programming: An Introduction to Computer Science (2nd Edition) by John Zelle**.

It says:

> Write a program that approximates the value of π by summing the terms
>   of this series: 4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7 + 4/9 - 4/11 + ... The program
>   should prompt the user for n, the number of terms to sum, and then
>   output the sum of the first n terms of this series. Have your program
>   subtract the approximation from the value of math.pi to see how
>   accurate it is.

Here is what I have done:

```
# pi_approximation
#   Program which approximates the value of Pi by summing the terms of
#   this series: 4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7

import math

def main():

    print("Welcome to Pi approximation!\n")

    n = int(input("Enter the number of terms to sum: "))

    approx = 0

    for i in range(1, n+1, 2):
        approx += 4 / i - 4 / (i+2)

    print("Approximate value of pi is: " + str(approx))

    print("Deviation from Pi is: " + str(math.pi - approx))

main()
```

I'm using Python 3.6.

Comment: *I am having concerns with the validity of the code I wrote*.... this is really vague. What kind of concerns? What's the specific problem you're having? Did you test it? Do you get an error? Do you get results that aren't correct?

Comment: Did you test it? The answer doesn't converge to PI for me...

Comment: Maybe post to [codereview.se], but be very specific on the kind of feedback you're looking for.

Comment: Yes I have tested it, and it seems to me that the results aren't correct - for instance, if I enter 5 as n, I get 3.6363636363636367.

Comment: @PeterWood I actually had and have received 3 downvotes, so...I should better stick with you guys.

Comment: @leovp Possibly the code is wrong, but the series actually converges to Pi. The problem is it converges **very, very slowly** — one needs half million terms to obtain five digits of Pi accurate. See Wikipedia [Pi#Rate of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Rate_of_convergence).

Comment: @CiaPan this code is indeed wrong (the for loop uses jumps of only 2 instead of 4). the original series converges to pi, but the OP is not using it right, hence it won't converge to pi

Comment: What value would you expect for `n = 5`? Google gives [**`3.33968253968`**](https://www.google.de/search?q=4%2F1+-+4%2F3+%2B+4%2F5+-+4%2F7+%2B+4%2F9&oq=4%2F1+-+4%2F3+%2B+4%2F5+-+4%2F7+%2B+4%2F9&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59.3972j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: With the correction @noob has suggested, it gives me 2.8952380952380956. When I enter 500.000 as n, it gives me 3.141588653589836

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete solution:

```
# pi_approximation
#   Program which approximates the value of Pi by summing the terms of
#   the Gregory-Leibniz series: 4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7

from math import pi as PI

def main():
    print("Welcome to Pi approximation!\n")
    n = int(input("Enter the number of terms to sum: "))
    approx = 0
    sign = -1

    # -- start Gregory-Leibniz series

    for i in range(1, n+1):  # do this 'n' times
        sign *= -1
        approx += sign * ( 4 / (2*i - 1) )

    # -- end Gregory-Leibniz series

    print("Approximate value of pi is:", approx)

    difference = PI - approx
    print("Deviation from Pi is:", difference)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

`for i in range(1, n+1, 2):` should be `for i in range(1, n+1, 4):` since you sum the i part AND the i+2 part

Comment: I edited my question. At the start I thought you only want to sum the series, I didn't notice you want to check the abs(pi - aprox)

Comment: If that was the only mistake, then I have a working program?

Comment: yes. it should <script src="http://ideone.com/e.js/Lvv8B3" type="text/javascript" ></script>

Comment: If I had for i in range(1, n+1, 4), I would have 1, 5, 9, 13...and if the user wants, for instance, first four terms - it will be: 4/1 - 4/5. So, for loop should count from 1 to n+1 without jumps. Here is the solution: for i in range(1, n+1):
  if i%2 != 0:
    approx += 4 / (2*i-1)
  else:
    approx -= 4 / (2*i-1)

Comment: what? no! that's just writing the same thing in a lengthy way

Answer (score 0):

Here is a combination of previous answers (which helped me out, thanks) with powerful Python features, list comprehension and iterator function, that crunch the whole algorithm into a single line. Also in my opinion, for n terms, range should stop before 2*n+1 because we only use odd numbers.

```
approx = sum([4/i - 4/(i+2) for i in range(1, 2*n+1, 4)])
```

Test results when combined with complete source prove it converges with big number of terms:

> $ python3 leibniz.py
>  
>   Welcome to Pi approximation!
>
> Enter the number of terms to sum: 2000
>   Approximate value of pi is: 3.1410926536210386
>   Deviation from Pi is: 0.0004999999687544943